# Ошибка "Vector subscriptout of range''

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

Начал недавно учиться программировать на c++
при выборе функции enter()  во второй раз, моя программа выдаёт ошибку vector subscript out of range

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <clocale>

void menu();
void enter();
void hide();
void size();

using namespace std;

struct ty
{
    string name;
    string region;
    long population;
    string stat;
};


vector<ty> sities(1);


int main()
{
    string mestr;
    while (mestr != "q" || mestr != "Q")
    {
        menu();
        cout << "Command: _\b";
        cin >> mestr;
        if (mestr == "e" || mestr == "E")
            enter();
        else if (mestr == "h" || mestr == "H")
            hide();
        else if (mestr == "s" || mestr == "S")
            size();
    }
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    cout << "Enter:\n   <q to exit>    <e to enter the city>   <h to hide>\n";
    cout << "   <s to show size>\n";
}
void enter()
{
    int * te = new int;
    *te = 0;
    sities.push_back(sities[*te]);
    while (sities[*te].name != "\0")
    {
        *te++;
    }
    cout << "Enter the name:\n";
    cin >> sities[*te].name;
    cout << "Enter the region:\n";
    cin >> sities[*te].region;
    cout << "Enter the population:\n";
    cin >> sities[*te].population;
    cout << "Enter tne stat:\n";
    cin >> sities[*te].stat;
    sities[*te + 1].name = "\0";
    sities[*te + 1].region = "\0";
    sities[*te + 1].population = 0;
    sities[*te + 1].stat = "\0";
    delete te;
}
void hide()
{
    cout << "Enter: ";
    string * nm = new string;
    int * th = new int;
    *th = 0;
    cin >> *nm;
    while (sities[*th].name != *nm)
    {
        *th++;
    }
    cout << "Informatiom:\n";
    cout << "  Region: " << sities[*th].region;
    cout << "  Population: " << sities[*th].population;
    cout << "  Stat: " << sities[*th].stat << endl;;
    delete nm;
    delete th;
}
void size()
{
    int * s = new int;
    *s = size(sities) - 1;
    cout << *s << " elements" << endl;
    delete s;
}
```

Всё перепробовал. Если есть ещё замечания по работе программы - пишите. `#include "stdafx.h"` обеспечивает доступ к заголовочному файлу.

Comment: А то, что "программа" компилироваться не будет, вас не смутило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как минимум, вы не пробовали вместо

```
while (sities[*te].name != "\0")
{
    *te++;
}
```

написать

```
while (sities[*te].name != "\0")
{
    (*te)++;
}
```

Вы меняете указатель, а не значение, на которое он указывает...

```
while (sities[*th].name != *nm)
{
    *th++;
}
```

Тут вы сами исправите? :)

Но объясните вообще, "какой черт занес вас на эти галеры?" (с) - зачем вам это нужно - динамические выделение одного `int`?

Кстати, как и непонятно какой первый элемент в `sities`:

```
vector<ty> sities(1);
```

Вы как-то очень хитро зануляете потом лишний элемент - зачем? не проще ли ограничиться проходом по существующим элементам вектора? Вобщем, моя бы воля - переписал все с нуля, уж очень у вас "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"...

P.S. Только оно все равно не будет нормально работать - например, при поиске в `hide` несуществующего имени...

P.P.S. Конечно, это не мое дело, но называть `hide` функцию поиска, а массив городов - `sities` - как-то не комильфо.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void menu();
void enter();
void hide();
void size();

using namespace std;

struct ty
{
 string name;
 string region;
 string regiontype;
 long population;
 string stat;
};


vector<ty> sities;

ty buffer;



int main()
{
 string mestr;
 menu();
 cout << "Command: _\b";
 cin >> mestr;
 while (mestr != "4")
 {
  if (mestr == "1")
   enter();
  else if (mestr == "2")
   hide();
  else if (mestr == "3")
   size();
  else if (mestr != "1" || mestr != "2" || mestr != "3" || mestr != "4") 
   cout << "\nUnknown command" << endl;
  menu();
  cout << "Command: _\b";
  cin >> mestr;
    }
 
 return 0;
}
void menu()
{
 cout << "Enter:\n   <1 to enter the city>   <2 to hide>\n";
 cout << "   <3 to show size>   <4 to exit>\n";
}
void enter()
{
 sities.push_back(buffer);
 int * te = new int;
 *te = size(sities) - 1;
 cout << "Enter the name: ";
 cin >> sities[*te].name;
 cout << "Enter the region: ";
 cin >> sities[*te].region >> sities[*te].regiontype;
 cout << "Enter the population: ";
 cin >> sities[*te].population;
 cout << "Enter the status: ";
 cin >> sities[*te].stat;
 delete te;
}
void hide()
{
 cout << "Enter: ";
 string * nm = new string;
 int * th = new int;
 int * th1 = new int;
 *th1 = size(sities);
 cin >> *nm;
 for (*th = 0; (*th) < (*th1); ++(*th)) {
  if (sities[*th].name == *nm)
  {
   cout << sities[*th].region << " " << sities[*th].regiontype <<
    "\nPopulation: " << sities[*th].population << "   Status: " << sities[*th].stat << endl;
   delete th;
  }
  else if (*th == *th1) 
  {
   cout << "Not found\n";
   delete th;
  }
 }
 
 delete nm, th1;
}
void size()
{
 int * s = new int;
 *s = size(sities);
 cout << *s << " elements" << endl;
 delete s;
}
```